# image display error using node.js and express.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Once i open 'localhost:3000' , the image is getting downloaded to my laptop instead of being displayed on the webpage , can anyone please help me out ?

```js
var express= require('express');
var fs = require('fs');
var app= express();

var imgpath= 'C:\Users\Rohit\Downloads\images.jpg';

app.get('/',function(req,res){
  res.send(fs.readFileSync(imgpath));
});

app.listen(3000);
console.log('listening');
```

Comment: You need to pass the image url to a view, so use `res.render('<view_file>');` and in that view write `<img src = "path">` to display on webpage.

Comment: can you explain why res.send wont work here , in the way it works for strings or json items ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to set header.

```
app.get('/',function(req,res){
  res.set('Content-Type', 'image/jpg');//Added line
  res.send(fs.readFileSync(imgpath));
});
```

Comment: i'm new to all this sir , can you explain why do we have to set header ?

Comment: By default browser expect content-type: text/html. Browser try to identify by extension of url if it is image or pdf. It can not be identified by extension then browser download the file.

Comment: but in the url - .jpg was mentioned , why couldn't it identify it as an image ?

Comment: by setting header img/jpg we recommend browser to handle it as image.

Comment: I have checked http://localhost:3000/abc.jpg by changing the code that as well downloading the image if we don't pass the header.

Comment: so , unless we recommend the browser it by default expects text/html ?

Answer (score 0):

you must set content-type

```
res.type('jpg').send(fs.readFileSync(imgpath));
```